# Where can I find recordings of people reading things now that mp3.baidu.com is dead?

Tags: pronunciation, resources, audio, listening

Baidu's MP3 search engine used to be my first stop when studying *anything* Chinese. Absurdly, even recordings of relatively rare poetry (for instance) were easy to find. *These recordings were not copyrighted, and were usually made by individuals just for fun*. It was often possible to hear the ambient sounds of people's houses in the background of the recordings. As a bonus, sentimental backing tracks were often included. For a language geek, it was a dream come true.

That said, mp3.baidu.com had an enemy. The last time I ever tried to download a recording, it was of a famous, funny Lu Xun story called Kong Yiji. Most of the download links failed, but when I found one that worked, it was a parody recording of "The Real Slim Shady" by someone with a Hubei accent.

What gives?

I'm aware that librivox has some recordings of Chinese poetry, but really for the amount of stuff that was previously accessible using mp3.baidu.com, it's a very poor substitute.

Comment: So it's a search engine for stories recorded by "normal" people? Was the quality good? Apart from background noises?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of listening material you want to find?

Comment: @Aleanno yes, the quality was good enough. they were educated native speakers after all.

Comment: @Village anything and everything literary. Short stories, poetry, prose, classical and modern alike.

Comment: Oh, it's dead? Shame.

Comment: mp3.baidu.com _never_ hosted any of the mp3s. They just index links. Furthermore, they're _not_ dead. Presumably whichever site was hosting the material you were listening to went offline. You should probably figure out what site that was.

Answer (score 1):

mp3.baidu.com is a music downloading site as far as I know...

If you are looking for professional Mandarin recording of selective Chinese articles (includes Lu Xun's article sometimes), I would suggest the [Yuedu.FM](http://yuedu.fm).

BTW, VeryCD is no longer a file-sharing site anymore because of copyright issue, and all download links has since been removed. However, the resource pages still active and now they link to many Online Video Streaming sites (but people outside China cannot view them because of region restrictions).

Comment: Hellow Md Gao. Please share those resources on [our community resource question](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/43). Make sure the links you post are *official*, *free* and above all *legal*. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I shared some link to there. :) and edited my answer to remove some link because I forgot the region restriction issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VeryCD](http://www.verycd.com/) which is a Chinese "peer-2-peer" file sharing service. I have found whole novels in mp3 format there.

Another file sharing system used over there is [Foxy](http://download.pchome.net/internet/server/proxy/detail-2532.html). However, it has had some security problems in the past.

As for copyright issues, same as with any other file sharing; if the material is copyrighted you shouldn't share it.

Comment: Can you also add if it requires registration? Is the registration free? Are there copyright issues? Such info would add more value to your answer.

Comment: verycd is the name of the site/client which like most sites of its nature (nfo site if you may), do not or do not need to actively enforce copyright since it does not host or serve the content itself. The p2p service network is actually edonkey or ed2k

Comment: Actually VeryCD is a website not a service. It provides eDonkey links, so as long as you go download and install eDonkey you can download from VeryCD, no registration needed.